# Promise.all returns data in a random order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was having problems with data fetching taking a long time, because i was fetching data in a loop like this:

```
    const req = await fetch(
      "https://www.supplier.co.uk/newarrivals/?setPerPage=25&search_direction=asc&pageID=" +
        page
    );
    const html = await req.text();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    let newProducts = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
      let pageSrc = $(
        `#product_listing > tbody > #_${i} > td:nth-child(2) > a`
      ).attr("href");

      pageSrc = "https://www.supplier.co.uk" + pageSrc;

      const req2 = await fetch(pageSrc);
      const html2 = await req2.text();
      const $2 = cheerio.load(html2);

      let imageSrc = $2(
        "#product-main-image .main-image-inner:first-child img"
      ).attr("src");
      const name = $2("#product-details dd:nth-child(2)")
        .text();
      const brand = $2("#product-details dd:nth-child(4)")
        .text();
      const price = $2("#product-details dd:nth-child(6)")
        .text();

      newProducts.push({
        name,
        imageSrc,
        brand,
        price,
        pageSrc,
      });
    }

    return newProducts;
```

With the help of people on here, i managed to change it so it will fetch all of the URLs in parallel using `Promise.all()` like this:

```
const pageSrcs = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
      let pageSrc = $(
        `#product_listing > tbody > #_${i} > td:nth-child(2) > a`
      ).attr("href");

      pageSrc = "https://www.supplier.co.uk" + pageSrc;
      pageSrcs.push(pageSrc);
    }

    await Promise.all(
      pageSrcs.map((pageSrc) =>
        fetch(pageSrc)
          .then((res) => res.text())
          .then((html2) => {
            const $2 = cheerio.load(html2);

            let imageSrc = $2(
              "#product-main-image .main-image-inner:first-child img"
            ).attr("src");
            const brand = $2("#product-details dd:nth-child(4)").text();
         //etc more selectors & functions
              newProducts.push({
              name,
              imageSrc,
              brand,
              price,
              pageSrc,
              stock,
              arrival,
              type,
            });
          })
      )
    );

    return newProducts;
```

But now the data gets returned in a random order, obviously since the requests are parallel. Is there a simple way to order them?

edit: added rest of code

Comment: According to the docs of [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) *"Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order"*. Try using the return value instead of chaining `then` inside the promise.all

Comment: Seems more likely they're _rendering_ in "random" order, or rather, as the individual requests resolve and the values from the requests become available.  I don't see any values being returned in the above code.

Comment: edit: added what gets returned - missed it off originally to save space

Answer (score 3):

You should use the return value from `Promise.all`, this will be in order. Currently you use the individual return values before they are collected by `Promise.all`

```js
    const texts = await Promise.all(
      pageSrcs.map((pageSrc) => fetch(pageSrc).then((res) => res.text()))
    )
    for (const html of texts) {
      const $2 = cheerio.load(html);
      let imageSrc = $2("#product-main-image .main-image-inner:first-child img").attr("src");
      const brand = $2("#product-details dd:nth-child(4)").text();
      //etc...
    }
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I'll give it a try! I did edit my post to be more clear what was being returned.